# WordPress meta boxes

Tags: arrays, database, wordpress, html-select, meta-boxes

Can anyone explain to me why this code is not save wp meta boxes select value from this array `$results`
The code below support to save the selected value from $results (from the array I only need one key which is groups), using foreach

```
public function ewa_custom_box_html( $post ) {
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_groups_name_meta_key', true );
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_groups";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
    echo '<label for="groups_name_field" id="groups_name_field">Select from groups</label>';
        echo '<select>';
        foreach ($results as $key) {
          echo '<option value="'.$key->groups.'">'.selected($key->groups, ). $key->groups .' </option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

After selected a value and it doesn't save! How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

After did some recherche, I finally find out where was the issues.
Create a new array to store data and then I use `foreach` loop to print all keys in `select html` full class on [github](https://gist.github.com/Muswamba/18f842c309dd3a16296d74bba4995991)

```
   //Getting values( Selet key from array )
   public function ewa_groups_names_html( $post ) {
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ewa_groups_name_meta_key', false );
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ewa_ads_groups";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
    $groups = [];
    foreach ($results as $key) {
      $groups[] = $key->groups;
    }
    // if (empty($groups)) return;
    ?>
    <label for="groups_name"><?php esc_html('Select from groups') ?></label>
   
       <select name="ewa_groups_name_field" id="groups_name">
          <option> <?php _e('-- Select groups --') ?></option>
           <?php
           foreach ($groups as $group) {
             echo '<option value="'.$group.'" '.selected($value, $group, ).'>'.$group.'</option>';
           }
            ?>
        </select> 
    <?php
  }
```

**Save meta boxes values**

```
    public function ewa_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['ewa_groups_name_field'])) {
      $gp = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ewa_groups_name_field']);

        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_ewa_groups_name_meta_key',
            $gp
        );
      }
  }
```